# Argument out of range error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My code is working intermittently, but sometimes gives me the argument out of range error and I can't figure out why, I've narrowed it down to one function:

```
void corridorFill()
{
    int dir = 0;
    //Set initial coords
    int rand = Random.Range(0,freeCol.Count);

    List<int> freeCorRow = new List<int>();
    List<int> freeCorCol = new List<int>();

    row = freeRow[rand];
    col = freeCol[rand];

    int fill = 0;

    while(fill < area)
    {
        //Pick a random direction and go that way
        //0 = north, 1 = east, 2 = south, 3 = west
        dir = Random.Range(0,4);

        if(directionIsSafe(dir, row, col, (int)room.Unreserved, roomType) 
            && directionIsSafe(dir, row, col, (int)connect.Empty, connections))
        {
            //move in direction
            moveDirection(dir); 

            freeCorRow.Add(row);
            freeCorCol.Add(col);

            if(fill > 0)
            {
                //place exit to previous tile
                addExit(row, col, (dir+2)%4);

                //change exits of previous room to connect
                addExit(freeCorRow[freeCorRow.Count-2], freeCorCol[freeCorCol.Count-2], dir);

            }

            fill++;
        }
        else
        {
            bool set = false;

            while(!set)
            {
                //direction is not safe therefore start again somewhere else, attached to what we already have
                int r = Random.Range(0,freeCorRow.Count);

                //check if a tile beside a known tile is free
                dir = Random.Range(0,4);

                //if the direction is safe, go that way
                if(directionIsSafe(dir, freeCorRow[r], freeCorCol[r], (int)room.Unreserved, roomType) 
                    && directionIsSafe(dir, freeCorRow[r], freeCorCol[r], (int)connect.Empty, connections))
                {
                    addExit(freeCorRow[r], freeCorCol[r], dir);

                    row = freeCorRow[r];
                    col = freeCorCol[r]; 
                    moveDirection(dir); //move in direction
                    addExit(row, col, (dir+2)%4); //place exit to previous tile

                    freeCorRow.Add(row);
                    freeCorCol.Add(col);

                    set = true;
                }
            }

            fill++;
        }
    }
}
```

which uses the addExit function, though I don't think the problem is here:

```
//check previous tile corridor configuration and change to match current
void addExit(int row, int col, int dir)
{
    //Add northourn exit to room
    if(dir == 0)
    {
        if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.Empty)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.N;
        }
        else if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.E)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.NE;
        }
        else if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.S)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.NS;
        }
        else if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.W)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.NW;
        }
        else if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.SE)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.NES;
        }
        else if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.SW)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.SWN;
        }
        else if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.EW)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.WNE;
        }
        else if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.ESW)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.NESW;
        }
    }

    //Add eastern exit to room
    if(dir == 1)
    {
        if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.Empty)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.E;
        }
        else if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.N)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.NE;
        }
        else if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.S)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.SE;
        }
        else if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.W)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.EW;
        }
        else if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.NW)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.WNE;
        }
        else if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.SW)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.ESW;
        }
        else if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.NS)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.NES;
        }
        else if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.SWN)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.NESW;
        }
    }

    //Add southourn exit to room
    if(dir == 2)
    {
        if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.Empty)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.S;
        }
        else if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.N)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.NS;
        }
        else if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.E)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.SE;
        }
        else if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.W)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.SW;
        }
        else if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.NE)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.NES;
        }
        else if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.NW)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.SWN;
        }
        else if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.EW)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.ESW;
        }
        else if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.WNE)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.NESW;
        }
    }

    //Add western exit to room
    if(dir == 3)
    {
        if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.Empty)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.W;
        }
        else if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.N)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.NW;
        }
        else if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.E)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.EW;
        }
        else if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.S)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.SW;
        }
        else if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.NE)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.WNE;
        }
        else if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.SE)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.ESW;
        }
        else if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.NS)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.SWN;
        }
        else if(connections[row,col] == (int)connect.NES)
        {
            connections[row,col] = (int)connect.NESW;
        }
    }
}
```

and the directionIsSafe function:

```
bool directionIsSafe(int dir, int row, int col, int roomname, int[,] checkType)
{
    if(dir == 0 && col+1 < stationHeight)
    {
        if(checkType[row, col+1] == roomname)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else if(dir == 1 && row+1 < stationWidth)
    {
        if(checkType[row+1,col] == roomname)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else if(dir == 2 && col > 0)
    {
        if(checkType[row,col-1] == roomname)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else if(dir == 3 && row > 0)
    {
        if(checkType[row-1,col] == roomname)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Reading through the code it seems like it should work, and it does some of the time, but not all of the time. I can't figure out why only sometimes it doesn't work. Appreciate any light you might shed on the problem

**EDT**

freeCol and freeRow are created using:

```
 if(genType == (int)shapes.cross)
    {
        //for odd numbers
        if(stationWidth%2 == 1)
        {
            for(row = 0; row < stationWidth; row++)
            {
                for(col = 0; col < stationHeight; col++)
                {
                    if((row <= stationWidth/2 + (crossArmSize/2.0f + 0.5f) - 1 && row >= stationWidth/2 - (crossArmSize/2.0f + 0.5f) + 1)
                        || (col <= stationHeight/2 + (crossArmSize/2.0f + 0.5f) - 1 && col >= stationHeight/2 - (crossArmSize/2.0f + 0.5f) + 1))
                    {
                        roomType[row,col] = (int)room.Unreserved;
                        freeRow.Add(row);
                        freeCol.Add(col);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //for even numbers
        else if(stationWidth%2 == 0)
        {
            for(row = 0; row < stationWidth; row++)
            {
                for(col = 0; col < stationHeight; col++)
                {
                    if((row < stationWidth/2 + crossArmSize/2 && row >= stationWidth/2 - crossArmSize/2)
                        || (col < stationWidth/2 + crossArmSize/2 && col >= stationWidth/2 - crossArmSize/2))
                    {
                        roomType[row,col] = (int)room.Unreserved;
                        freeRow.Add(row);
                        freeCol.Add(col);   
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        corridorFill();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I changed:

```
row = freeRow[rand];
col = freeCol[rand];
```

to:

```
    row = freeRow[Mathf.RoundToInt(stationWidth/2)];
    col = freeCol[Mathf.RoundToInt(stationHeight/2)];
```

and it works every time now. I just can't figure out why the former was throwing out weird results and just plain not working, if you can shed light on it I'd love to hear it!

Comment: You didn't show where `freeRow` or `freeCol` are defined, so I don't think it's possible to shed any light. Try using a debugger, or try to make a [MCVE].

Comment: Edited the question to include how those lists are filled

Answer (score 2):

I think Random.Range is inclusive.  Try `int rand = Random.Range(0,freeCol.Count - 1);`

Comment: It is indeed inclusive: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html

Comment: `Random.Range` has 2 overloads. `int` and `float`. `float` is inclusive and `int` is exclusive.

Comment: I'm using the int overload which is max exclusive so no problems there

Answer (score 0):

Are Width and Height swapped in the last function?
Normally rows go along the height and columns along the width.

Comment: Not in this case as the width and height are the same